# Java Byte Code Missing Local Variable Table

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

When I am checking the byte code of JDK1.7, I find the byte code of some Java classes (e.g., `javax.swing.event.EventListenerList`) in rt.jar does not include local variable table. For example, I use `javap -v -p -l EventListenerList.class` command and got the byte code of `add` method like:

```
public synchronized <T extends java.util.EventListener> void add(java.lang.Class<T>, T);
descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/util/EventListener;)V
flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SYNCHRONIZED
Code:
  stack=5, locals=5, args_size=3
     0: aload_2
     1: ifnonnull     5
     4: return
     5: aload_1
     6: aload_2
     7: invokevirtual #133                // Method java/lang/Class.isInstance:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    ...
   116: aload_0
   117: aload         4
   119: putfield      #128                // Field listenerList:[Ljava/lang/Object;
   122: return
  StackMapTable: number_of_entries = 4
    frame_type = 5 /* same */
    frame_type = 43 /* same */
    frame_type = 28 /* same */
    frame_type = 43 /* same */
  LineNumberTable:
    line 179: 0
    line 183: 4
    line 185: 5
    line 186: 13
    ...
    line 200: 109
    line 202: 116
    line 204: 122
Signature: #85                          // <T::Ljava/util/EventListener;>(Ljava/lang/Class<TT;>;TT;)V
```

We can see that the method has two local variables, but JDK byte code does not show local variable table. My questions are:

1. Why byte code without explicit local variable table is validated?
2. How can JVM get the start PC, name, and signature when running such byte code?

Answer (score 5):

The local variable table is only for debugging purposes - it doesn't have any direct effect on the execution of bytecode. You can tell javac leave them out by passing `-g:none`.

As for the second question, it doesn't. The JVM doesn't care about what variables you declared at the source level - all it sees is values being passed around in the bytecode.

Comment: Note that the default setting (`-g`) is to include the line numbers and the name of the source file, but no local variable tables. This is how the JDK classes have been compiled. Specifying `-g:none` would even skip line numbers (at least some JREs shipped with classes compiled this way).

Answer (score 0):

From `javac --help`

```
-g Generate all debugging info
```

If you have a class say `Temp.java`, then:

- `javac -g Temp.java`
- `javap -v Temp`

would give you `LocalVariableTable` in the output.

PS: Not sure how one will do for in-built classes like `javax.swing.event.EventListenerList`